On the diophantine equation $(2^m\pm1)(2^n\pm1)=x^k$
It is well known that the Catalan equation
$$x^m - 1 = y^n\ \ \ (m,n,x,y\in\{2,3,4,\ldots\})$$
has the unique solution $3^2-1=2^3$. Motivated by this and Question 485037, here I pose the following conjecture.
Conjecture. (i) The number $(2^3-1)(2^6-1)=21^2$ is the only perfect power of the form $(2^m-1)(2^n-1)$ with $1<m<n$.
(ii) The number $(2+1)(2^3+1)=3^3$ is the only perfect power of the form $(2^m+1)(2^n+1)$ with $0\le m<n$.
(iii) The only perfect powers of the form $(2^m-1)(2^n+1)$ with $m>0$ and $n\ge0$ are
$$(2-1)(2^3+1)=3^2,\ (2^2-1)(2+1)=3^2\ \ \text{and}\ \ (2^2-1)(2^3+1)=3^3.$$
I have verified the conjecture for $m,n\le300$.
As I'm not an expert at diophantine equations, here I ask the following question.
QUESTION. Is the conjecture known? Can one prove the conjecture by modifying Mihailescu's solution to Catalan's equation? Can one find a counterexample to the above conjecture?

Porf. Bo He told me that Lemma 3.2 of F. Luca and P. G. Walsh's paper [JNT 96 (2002), 152-173] gave all the solutions of the diophantine equation $(a^m-1)(a^n-1)=x^2$ with $m>n\ge1$ and $a\ge2$. Thus it is known that $21^2$ is the only square of the form $(2^m-1)(2^n-1)$ with $1<m<n$.
